# How to set notifications badge over app icon

Tags: java, android

I created a messaging app, I want when some user send a message to another user then that user receives notifications badges over there app icon.

It should be work even app is closed or killed.

Thanks in advance.

I tried some libraries of GitHub but not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature the of Android system. Device manufacturers (like Xiaomi you mentioned) or launcher developers (like Nova Launcher) can implement it and expose an api for app developers, but there is no standard for that, nor is it expected by the users to be there.